# Handling API json

Tags: python, json

```
{
  "token_type": "bearer",
  "stripe_publishable_key": "{PUBLISHABLE_KEY}",
  "scope": "read_write",
  "livemode": false,
  "stripe_user_id": "{ACCOUNT_ID}",
  "refresh_token": "{REFRESH_TOKEN}",
  "access_token": "{ACCESS_TOKEN}",
}
```

I am working with third party api using python requests and can grab stripe_user_id from the above json response using this:

stripe_payload = json.loads(resp.text)

stripe_user_id = stripe_payload['stripe_user_id']

How would I grab the api_token below when the json is returned as below with the extra "data" inserted in the json response?

I tried this: timekit_api_token = timekit_payload['data':'api_token'] but got an error: unhashable type: 'slice'

```
{
    "data": {
    "id": "d187d6e0-d6cb-409a-ae60-45a8fd0ec879",
    "first_name": "Emmet",
    "last_name": "Brown",
    "name": "Emmet Brown",
    "email": "doc.brown@timekit.io",
    "image": "http://www.link-to-img.com/image.png",
    "activated": false,
    "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "last_sync": null,
    "api_token": "nvHfRSlhvsnlg4rS7Wt28Ty47qdgegwSu3YK7hPW"
 }
}
```

Comment: try with `timekit_api_token = timekit_payload['data']['api_token']`, when you have nested dictionaries, just add the keys you are looking for

Comment: One more thing: You can get a dictionary directly in Python by doing r = requests.get(URL).json() - Might be helpful